# How to iterate through the built-in types in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to iterate through the built-in types (bool, char, sbyte, byte, short, ushort, etc) in c#.

How to do that?

```
foreach(var x in GetBuiltInTypes())
{
//do something on x
}
```

Comment: Only the primitive value types?

Comment: @Bolt: yes, the primitive ones only.

Comment: Since they are built in (and not likely to change any time soon, maybe just make an enum with all the types and then iterate over that with a `foreach(Type builtInType in MyEnumTypes)`. . .?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[System.TypeCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.typecode.aspx) is the closest thing I can think of.

```
foreach(TypeCode t in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TypeCode)))
{ 
    // do something interesting with the value...
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. Thank you. For other solutions, thank you as well.

Comment: Here, have a "Nice Answer" badge :)

Answer (score 6):

It depends on how you define "built-in" types of course.

You might want something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetBuiltInTypes()
{
   return typeof(int).Assembly
                     .GetTypes()
                     .Where(t => t.IsPrimitive);
}
```

This should give you (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx)):

Boolean, Byte, SByte, Int16, UInt16, Int32, UInt32, Int64, UInt64, IntPtr, UIntPtr, Char, Double, and Single.

If you have a different definition, you might want to enumerate all of the types in common BCL assemblies (such as mscorlib, System.dll, System.Core.dll etc.), applying your filter as you go along.

Comment: Ah, the beauty (and slowness) of LINQ! Those solutions are always creative. :)

Comment: can we make a single function `GetBuiltInTypes` for all built-in primitive types including string, char, integer variants?

Comment: System.TypeCode would provide string, char, and integer variants in one place.

Comment: If you use LINQ, I think it'd be nice to use `return from type in typeof(int).Assembly.GetTypes() where type.IsPrimitive select type;` instead; what do you think? :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: I don't have a strong preference in this case between the two syntaxes. IMO, both are equally readable.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to do that; you can try:

```
foreach (var type in new Type[] { typeof(byte), typeof(sbyte), ... })
{
    //...
}
```

Of course, if you're going to be doing this a lot, factor out the array and put it inside a `static readonly` variable.

Comment: This is invalid syntax. Did you perhaps mean foreach (var type *in* ...)?

Comment: @Cameron: Ooops, yeah... I was thinking half in D, half in C#. Thanks! :)

Comment: I just changed it, yeah it was a typo.