# How to get all the system types or built in types used in a C# class

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am trying to list all the system types used in a C# class. For example,

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
    }
    private void SomeMethod(float parm1, double param2)
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"AssemblyName");
    }
}
```

Here I want to list,

> 1. Int32
> 2. Console
> 3. Void
> 4. Assembly
> 5. float
> 6. double
> 7. string

How to do this?

Comment: Does this even Compile?

Comment: @Sadiq : Sorry,  Now I have edited the question.

Comment: You could just iterate members (methods and properties) using reflection and find necessary type info. It is the `int` part which makes this question tricky. I don't think answerers here got the point of your question. Good question, +1

Comment: How do you define "system types"?

Comment: How is this related to `roslyn`?

Comment: @SLaks : Here the "System types" means the Microsoft defined types (not the user defined types) in a C# project. So far I am recognizing with the full name of the types, those will start with the namespace "System.xxx". This may fail, if we give our own namespaces like "System.OurCustom.XXX", but do not find any other better way.

Comment: @PauloMorgado : I am achieving this with Roslyn by building a SemanticModel of classes. Then iterating through Field, Property and Method declarations in a class. If I found a declaration, then I will check whether this is a System type or not (Please see the previous comment for SLaks). I like to know whether this is the only way or any other better way exists.

Comment: So you could define your condition of "system type" as being something like "it's defined in an assembly" or "it's defined in an assembly signed by the Microsoft key" or a number of other possible ways to do it.

Answer (score -3):

Look into [How to iterate through the built-in types in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201630/how-to-iterate-through-the-built-in-types-in-c)

```
typeof(int).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsPrimitive);
```

Comment: This will only return the basic primitive types. The types "Assembly" and "Void" can be used with this

Comment: you need to loop through assembly list. var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies(); or all assemblies from GAC